# Соединить zfill() с словарем

Tags: python

Есть словарь:

```
bon={'998303009200': ['3193', '54.5', 'FIO_1'],'998330562828': ['5583', '80.0', 'FIO_2'],
 '998330697741': ['5033', '246.8', 'FIO_3']}
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как пройтись с циклом и  используя функцию zfill() добавить 1 ноль к '3193', '5583' и '5033'.
И сделать '03193', '05583' и '05033' и так далее.
Спасибо.

Comment: 1 - пишите цикл for, 2 - проходитесь по значениям в словаре (`bon.values()`), 3 - в каждом значении (списке) меняете первый элемент как вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Пройтись по значениям словаря в цикле и поменять первый элемент каждого:

```
bon = {
    '998303009200': ['3193', '54.5', 'FIO_1'],
    '998330562828': ['5583', '80.0', 'FIO_2'],
    '998330697741': ['5033', '246.8', 'FIO_3']
}
for values in bon.values():
    values[0] = values[0].zfill(5)
print(bon)
# {'998303009200': ['03193', '54.5', 'FIO_1'], '998330562828': ['05583', '80.0', 'FIO_2'], '998330697741': ['05033', '246.8', 'FIO_3']}
```